# Why must the order of basepoint of elliptic curve be prime?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, elliptic-curves

Let $E$ be an elliptic curve defined over a finite field $F(q)$. Let $G\in E(F(q))$ be a point of order $n$, where $n$ is a prime number and $n>2^{160}$.

The elliptic curve discrete logarithm problem (ECDLP) is the following: given $E, G, Q \in E(F(q))$, determine the integer $l$, $0 \le l \le n-1$, such that $Q = lG$, is computationaly difficult.

My question is:
Why must $n$, the order of basepoint of this elliptic curve, be prime?

Answer (score 2):

The short answer is that it doesn't have to be a prime, and for most elliptic curves (in a suitable sense of "most") and for most choices $G$ $n$ is not a prime.

However, for practical EC-cryptosystems we design the curve, and select the point $G$ in such a way that the group generated by $G$ **is** of prime order.  Often it then also happens that the group generated by $G$ consists of all the $F(q)$-rational points. This latter requirement is not  necessary, but having it means that we are in a way using the elliptic curve very efficiently, we don't have to constrain our selves to  a subset of the available points.

The former property that we prefer groups of prime order comes from the fact that such elliptic curves tend to be safer. If $n$ were a product of small prime powers, we could relatively easily solve the DLP problem on that curve with the aid of easy to generate smallish look-up-tables and the Chinese Remainder Theorem. For the the curve to be safe, it is not sufficient that $n$ is a prime, but it helps for this reason (and may be deemed necessary).

So to summarize: these properties do not hold for all elliptic curves. But they do hold for those curves that are recommended for cryptographi standards.

Answer (score 1):

Because, if $n$ is not a prime, then there may not exist such an $l$.

To understand this, consider the following simpler situation. Consider the finite group $\mathbb Z/n\mathbb Z$ where $n$ is a prime number. Let $j, k$ be integers such that their congruence classes modulo $n$ are nonzero. Then, if $n$ is a prime number, there always exists an $l$ such that $lj \equiv k\ (\textrm{mod}\ n)$. This is a basic fact and easily follows from [Langrange's theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange%27s_theorem_%28group_theory%29) in group theory. Also for each composite number $n$, you can construct examples of $j,k$ that don't satisfy such an equation.

So $n$ being a prime number makes the situation neater and also contributes to computational complexity -- the composite case can be reduced further depending on prime factorization, which simplification is not possible for numbers which are already primes.

Comment: This partly misses the point. The existence of $\ell$ depends only on $G$ being a generator of the group. If the group of $F(q)$-rational points happens to be cyclic, such a $G$ exists (and vice versa). Where you mislead to think that $G$ is an arbitrary point on the curve? That is not the case here! An elliptic curve for a crypto standard comes with a precalculated generator $G$.

Comment: Hmm indeed. I didn't seem to have understood the question correctly. Thanks for the clarifications!

Comment: Not really your fault. The OP failed to provide that bit. Happens easily, if crypto practitioners are not fully conversant with algebra terminology.

Comment: Thanks for the kind words. Nevertheless as I re-read the question, the OP seems to have mentioned it as part of the first sentence. So it may after all be my own fault for not reading carefully and also for wading into stuff like cryptography which isn't my forte.